# How to assign value in DialogField from code?

Tags: dialog, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I created a *Dialog* , when I launch the *Dialog* I want to assign a value for **field**.

I have this code:

```
Dialog dialog;

myDialogField = dialog.addField(enumStr(myEnumType));
myDialogField.value(myVariableEnum); 

dialog.run();
```

With this code I can not assign variabe.
I launch the *Dialog* by button on *Form* , in a class I saw the really value in *myVariableEnum* but I don't know how to assign.

Thanks all,

enjoy!

Comment: The value assignment should work, but your code seems to be incomplete because the `dialog` variable is never instantiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dialog needs to be instantiated as FH-Inway pointed out, but you also need to use the field.value() as a getter to use the fields value after you run the dialog:

```
Dialog dialog;
DialogField myDialogField;

dialog = new dialog();
myDialogField = dialog.addField(enumStr(NoYesError), "Values : ");
myDialogField.Value(NoYesError::Yes);

dialog.run();

info(myDialogField.value());//This gets the value of the field after the dialog is run.
```

[image: Resulting dialog box]